# how to dplyr::inner_join multi tbls or data.frames in R

Tags: r, inner-join, dplyr

In R, how can I `inner_join` multiple `tbls` or `data.frame`s effectively?

For example:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/EDAWR")
library(EDAWR)
library(dplyr)
data(songs)
data(artists)
test <- songs
colnames(test) <- c("song2", "name")
inner_join(songs, artists,by="name") %>% inner_join(test,by="name")
```

There are hundreds `test`-like `data.frames` that I want join.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could collect the data frames in a list and use `Reduce`:

```
L <- list(songs, artists, test)
Reduce(inner_join, L)

#   name  plays                song               song2
# 1 John guitar Across the Universe Across the Universe
# 2 John guitar       Come Together Across the Universe
# 3 John guitar Across the Universe       Come Together
# 4 John guitar       Come Together       Come Together
# 5 Paul   bass      Hello, Goodbye      Hello, Goodbye
```

You can use `L <- mget(ls())` (with an optional `pattern` arg to `ls`) to get everything into a list.

---

As @akrun mentioned in the comments, a `plyr` alternative is:

```
library(plyr)
join_all(L, type='inner')
```

Comment: There is a difference between `Reduce` and `plyr::join_all` from the manual. The para, `by`. This works when the `colnames(test) ` is the same as data songs. (NOT TEST!). In the `Reduce` situation, it will use all the same colnames to join.

Comment: This is a very nice approach. I wonder if you can add `by` argument of `join` in `Reduce()`.

Comment: @jazzurro Well you can `Reduce(function(x, y) inner_join(x, y, by=c('foo' = 'bar')), L)`, but I think that would require that the `by` column for element 1 is `foo`, and for all subsequent elements it's `bar`.

Comment: @jbaums Thank you very much for that. It seems that renaming the key column beforehand (assigning identical column names to the key columns) is helpful then?

Comment: @jazzurro That sounds sensible to me, and probably just about as easy as if you could have passed all the names to `by` anyway.

Comment: @jbaums Thank you very much. This is a powerful technique.